# Get store email addresses by store ID

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have changed store email for another store.

Using below code I get a email of default config.

```
$FromName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');
$FromEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
```

I want another email address which i have changed for specific store only.

Is there any way to fetch store email by store id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the answer below, You need to pass the current store to get an Email Id...

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore(); // store info
$FromName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name',$store);
$FromEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email',$store);
```